# simultaneous (for) loops and (if all) for type

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

Is there a way to collapse these two "for" loops without having to reopen the text file?

```
hamletlines = []
hamletwords = []

hamlettext = open("hamlet.txt", "r")
for line in hamlettext.read().split('\n'):
    hamletlines.append(line)
hamlettext.closed  

hamlettext = open("hamlet.txt", "r")    
for word in hamlettext.read().split():
    hamletwords.append(word)
hamlettext.closed    

print("There are ", len(hamletlines), "lines and ", len(hamletwords), "words in Hamlet Text.")
print(type(hamletwords))
```

Next, I'd like to check if all of the types from a given list are strings but it's showing *'bool' object is not iterable*

```
if all(type(hamletwords)=='str'):
    print("all words are strings")
else:
    print("not all words are strings")
```

Comment: should be `all(type(x)==str for x in hamletwords)`, but anyway, all items of your list are strings already so it's useless to check. what should it be else?

Comment: @Jean-Francois Fabre, thanks! works great - this is just simply a series of exercises so ideally the creation of the string would not be in the same code as the one checking them as string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do it in a loop at all? Just let the (built-in, fast, C-based) methods take care of it.

```
HAMLET_FILE = "hamlet.txt"

with open(HAMLET_FILE) as inf:
    text = inf.read()

hamlet_lines = text.split("\n")
hamlet_words = text.split()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use another loop inside the first one :

```
hamlettext = open("hamlet.txt", "r")
for line in hamlettext.read().split('\n'):
    hamletlines.append(line)
    for word in line.split():
        hamletwords.append(word)
```